# Angular async pipe is not refreshing when observable changed

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have an Angular app.

- On the app init we should show redirecting spinner (user is not logged in)
- When the user is logged in, then we should show content

I've done it as below:
HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="(isLoggedIn$ | async); else loading">
    <!-- some other content -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
    <app-spinner text="Redirecting..."></app-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

TS:

```
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

It works well on the app init. When the user is logged in, I still see the redirection spinner. I have to refresh the window to see the router-outlet content.

My temporary workaround is to put `<router-outlet>` inside `<ng-template #loading>`, eg:

```
<ng-template #loading>
    <app-spinner text="Redirecting..."></app-spinner>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- HERE workaround -->
</ng-template>
```

But don't want to use this workaround permanently as I want to fix this Observable problem - as I mentioned it is not refreshed even when the console.log() says that I'm logged in.

Here is my Auth Service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  manager: UserManager = new UserManager(environment.settings);

  constructor() {
  }

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return from(this.manager.getUser());
  }

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUser()
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          return user != null && !user.expired;
        })
      );
  }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Observable<User> {
    return from(this.manager.signinRedirectCallback());
  }

  async signOut() {
    await this.manager.signoutRedirect();
  }
}
```

Of course, I am using `CanActivate` as well.

Comment: Can we see the code of `this.authService.isLoggedIn`?

Comment: How is this a workaround? Doesn't the app-spinner still spin?

Comment: Don't conditionally remove the `<router-outlet>` because the router can not active a route. This has nothing to do with the `isLoggedIn$` observable.

Comment: If you want to control routing, then use one of the router features. CanActivate for example.

Comment: @ConnorsFan here you are, post updated. @Jesse no, the spinner isn't spinning when `router-outlet` activates other components (it is visible in HTML source code but not in the view) @Reactgular I'm using CanActivate :)

Comment: Just to be sure - _does_ the observable emit? Maybe `tap` it with `console.log` to check.

Comment: @mbojko you're right, it doesn't emit anything

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add `emitCompleted` method to `AuthService` and calling it from `AuthCallback` component.

AuthService:

```
private isLoggedInState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoggedInState.asObservable();
}

emitCompleted(user: User) {
    this.isLoggedInState.next(user != null && !user.expired);
}
```

AuthCallback component:

```
export class AuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.completeAuthentication()
      .subscribe((result => {
        this.authService.emitCompleted(result);
      })
    );
  }
}
```